# What is the best way to create an settings page

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I want to make an Android application that controls an Raspberry Pi (singleboard computer).
To do that, I want to create a control page like the one below:

[image: control page]

As you can see, there are section headers, listview items with a switch, listview-items with a checkbox and listview-items with only text and listview-items that go to a new activity(of fragment).

I want to create the same thing for my android application. But I want to know what the best way is to create a page like this. I have already tried a listview with a CustomListAdapter, but the problem is that ALL my listview-items have a switch or ALL my listview-items have a checkbox, and so on.

So is it better to create a page like this in an other way? (build it mostly in the layout file, item for item?).

Comment: It's nothing but a PreferenceScreen... You need to read something about Preferences, uh? For reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android API includes an easy way to handle this. You need to create a `PreferenceActivity`. The Android API documentation provides a full, thorough explanation with examples. You can find that [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html)